# save child model() in Yii

Tags: yii

Suppose I have two database tables. One for Forms and another for Fields:

Forms:
`ID(pk),user_id,name,description`

Fields:
`ID(pk),form_id(fk),name,description`

The parent "Form" form has also the input form fields for the child "Fields" table like, `fields.name` and `fields.description`.

What I need is: whenever I put the values to the form it saves all the fields to their corresponding attributes, including the child "Field" form inputs. Like the Form table will store its own fields, *and* the Fields will store its own fields.

So how to make this work? I think "save child model" should be used? But don't know how to use save child model as I am a newbie to Yii.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the child by looping all the child and save it (if the child is more than one). For example the $_POST value that submit to the controller you can set it to become like this

`$_POST['con']['user_id'] = 1

$_POST['con']['name']='Andrew'

$_POST['con']['child'][1]['name'] = 'Some child1'

$_POST['con']['child'][1]['description']='some description'

etc...`

Then you can get these post values by using this

`$model->attributes = $_POST['con'];

$model->save();

foreach($model->children as $key=>$child){

$child->attributes = $_POST['con']['child'][$key];

$child->save();

}`

Note, this is just concept, hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

See Tabular Input in the Yii Ultimate Guide:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

(I don't see saveChildModel() in the Yii docs at all...)

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
if(isset($_POST['form'] && isset($_POST['fields']){
  $forms->attributes =$_POST['form']
  $fields->attributes =$_POST['fields']

  $valid=$forms->validate();
  $valid=$valid && $fields->validate();  
  if($valid){
          $forms->save(false); //to cancel validation
          $fields->save(false); //to cancel validation
     }
}
```